# How to run xmpp in background in ios 10?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I made chat app in ios but in ios 10 xmpp not working in background.

For that i have found one solution  pushkit used for run xmpp in background but i not understand how to implement xmpp + push kit.

So any one have idea or code about xmpp +push kit or ios 10 xmpp run in background then please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Before iOS 10, we have a voip socket which will wake your app up even in background if some packets are received even in background. But since iOS 10, we will not get the cpu time, so pushkit will be te last resort.

If you want to use pushkit, you must make sense it's just a way to wake you up when you are suspended or even you are killed. When you want to send a message to the remote one, you will need to send a http push message to APNS, and the message with its payload will be delivered (If it's enough, you can even skip your xmpp part).

If you insist on the xmpp communication, you may need to store the message after you send the APNS message, and when the remote app is waked up and connected to your xmpp server, the server send all the cached messages to the client to make these messages delivered.

It's quite complex as some changes are really necessary on your server.

Comment: thanks for giving me answer.i will try using APNS push notification.

Comment: @DivyaPatel, I am wondering why you need to use xmpp? It's quite a heavy protocol, if your app is focusing on instant chat, I think it's hard to change the behavior without server. If it's just for some kind of notification, the apple push may be a choice.

Comment: you are right it's heavy protocol but it's client requirement. :) and  Also i need group chat that's why i am using xmpp.

Comment: @DivyaPatel, I think then you can only use push notification as a method to wake app up, the server should do something to cache the messages and deliver them to client when client wake up and reconnect to server. Hope it can help you.